# ROS in VMWare, No information shown in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed  ROS on a VMWare Ubuntu image on a MAC.
I am using a kinect camera, when I run roslaunch openni_camera openni_kinect.launch,
it is good. but there is nothing shows in rviz, no message could be received.
When I use a rosbag file, it is good. Could you help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9056/ros-in-vmware,-no-information-shown-in-rviz/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2012-02-03**:
Looks to me like rviz is not the problem here.  Question states "When I use a rosbag file, it is good."  Doesn't it sound more like a problem with  openni?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As others have reported lately, rviz does not usually work well in a
virtual machine. It seems to need access to real 3D graphics hardware
for adequate performance.

The usual workaround is installing Ubuntu in a separate partition with
dual boot.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-06**:
@tfoote : Sure worth a note ! ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had better success using Parallels for RVIZ.  Parallels supports OpenGL acceleration in the virtual machine, and has worked with RVIZ in the past.

On older versions of Parallels (5), there was a slight workaround because Parallels Tools didn't get OpenGL properly working.  I believe that it was due to a library being incorrectly installed.  This workaround only works if you currently have NO openGL acceleration (For example, Compiz doesn't work).

1. Open terminal: sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/GL.conf
2. In Gedit: delete "mesa"
3. Line should read: /usr/lib/
4. Save and Close
5. Reboot

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-09-11**:
As of Parallels 7, this just works.  No modifications necessary.